# How can I work with raw bytes in perl

Tags: perl, encryption, byte

Documentation all directs me to unicode support, yet I don't think my request has anything to do with Unicode.  I want to work with raw bytes within the context of a single scalar; I need to be able to figure out its length (in bytes), take substrings of it (in bytes), write the bytes to disc, and over the network.  Is there an easy way to do this, without treating the bytes as any sort of encoding in perl?

**EDIT**

More explicitly,

```
my $data = "Perl String, unsure of encoding and don't need to know";
my @data_chunked_into_1024_bytes_each = #???
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perl strings are, conceptually, strings of *characters*, which are positive 32-bit integers that (normally) represent Unicode code points.  A byte string, in Perl, is just a string in which all the characters have values less than 256.

(That's the conceptual view.  The internal representation is somewhat more complicated, as the perl interpreter tries to store byte strings — in the above sense — as actual byte strings, while using a generalized UTF-8 encoding for strings that contain character values of 256 or higher.  But this is all *supposed* to be transparent to the user, and in fact mostly is, except for some ugly historical corner cases like the bitwise not (`~`) operator.)

As for how to turn a general string into a byte string, that really depends on what the string you have contains and what the byte string is *supposed* to contain:

- If your string already *is* a string of bytes — e.g. if you read it from a file in binary mode — then you don't need to do anything.  The string shouldn't contain any characters above 255 to being with, and if it does, that's an error and will probably be reported as such by the encryption code.
- Similarly, if your string is supposed to encode text in the ASCII or ISO-8859-1 encodings (which encode the 7- and 8-bit subsets of Unicode respectively), then you don't need to do anything: any characters up to 255 are already correctly encoded, and any higher values are invalid for those encodings.
- If your input string contains (Unicode) text that you want to encode in some *other* encoding, then you'll need to convert the string to that encoding.  The usual way to do that is by using the [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) module, like this:

  ```
  use Encode;
  my $byte_string = encode( "name of encoding", $text_string );
  ```

  Obviously, you can convert the byte string back to the corresponding character string with:

  ```
  use Encode;
  my $text_string = decode( "name of encoding", $byte_string );
  ```
- For the special case of the UTF-8 encoding, it's also possible to use the built-in [`utf8::encode()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) function instead of `Encode::encode()`:

  ```
  utf8::encode( $string );
  ```

  which does essentially the same thing as:

  ```
  use Encode;
  $string = encode( "utf8", $string );
  ```

  Note that, unlike `Encode::encode()`, the `utf8::encode()` function modifies the input string directly.  Also note that the `"utf8"` above refers to Perl's extended UTF-8 encoding, which allows values outside the official Unicode range; for strictly standards-compliant UTF-8 encoding, use `"utf-8"` with a hyphen ([see Encode documentation for the gory details](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8)).  And, yes, there's also a `utf8::decode()` function that does pretty much what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, very informative.  I ended up just writing to a tmp file and then reading back x "characters" after opening the file and calling `binmode`.  Data sizes aren't large, but I'll have to go back later and use the encode functionality which now makes sense to me.

Comment: This long-winded horseshit does not answer the question. The question is how to break a string into bytes regardless of encoding.

Comment: @felwithe: I'm sorry you feel that way. The question as you've phrased it, however, is either trivial or unanswerable. If your string is already a byte string, then there is nothing to do: it has already been "broken into bytes". If your string is a Unicode character string, then there is no way to "break it into bytes" without knowing *how* you want to encode those Unicode characters into bytes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, what you want is the pack/unpack functions: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html

Answer (score 1):

As long as your string doesn't contain characters above codepoint 255, it will mostly work as plain byte string, with `length` and `substr` operating on bytes. Additionally, most output functions like `print` expect octets/bytes by default and will actually complain if you try to stuff anything else to them.

You may need to explicitly encode/decode your output if it is known to be in some encoding, but more details can only be added if you ask another specific question for each problematic part of your program.